# git merge does not produce conflict on code deletion

Tags: git, merge

A co-worker and I are in the planning & testing stages for converting our development group to using git as the source control tool.  We have established a workflow that emphasizes code safety and workflow simplicity.  However, in testing different merge cases, I have found situations where `git merge` will automatically merge differences when it seems a conflict and manual merge would be the safer option.

Example:
Branch origin/master contains a single script file which has functions `foo()` and `bar()` as commit C1.  Two users each checkout C1 locally on their machines to make changes.  User1 adds function `baz()` and removes function `foo()`.  He does a fast-forward merge and pushes his changes back to origin/master as C2.  User2 modifies `bar()` so it calls `foo()` and commits his changes to C3.  He runs a fetch and merge to bring in any changes from origin/master and git performs a recursive merge into C4 that results in a file that contains only `bar()` and `baz()` where `bar()` is now broken because it calls `foo()` which no longer exists.

Question:
I realize I can setup a custom merge driver to automatically cause a conflict in these situations (and I've done so) in order to force manual merges.  However, this seems to be such a fundamental issue with git that I'm surprised nobody else is discussing it.  Am I missing something or is a custom merge driver the best way to handle this?

One last thing, I realize there are tools available to fix this after-the-fact, but fixing during merge seems the cleanest and most straight-forward method.

edit:  I realize git can't detect broken code, but it *can* detect that a file was changed in both branches from the nearest common ancestor and I would think producing a conflict is safer than automatically merging.  My custom merge driver accomplishes this, but I wanted to see if there was a Better Way(TM).

Comment: Git manages code, not logic. You're asking your version controller to do what your unit testing protocol should do.

Comment: True. This might be more understandable when you think about different files: think about the situation where `foo()` and `bar()` each are in a separate file. Modifying the bar-file as you described then clearly is unrelated to any changes in the foo-file.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks for the response.  Allow me to clarify:  I'm not wanting git to validate the call to `foo()`, I'm wanting git to avoid actions that are likely to cause code trampling.  Yes, we could detect the errors in testing and then go back and fix the merge errors, but then we could just automatically merge _all_ conflicts and resolve them the same way.

Comment: Define "code trampling" if it doesn't simply mean broken logic. What would be the algorithm to detect it?

Comment: @C-Otto That's true, but it would seem reasonable (and safer) to assume that changes contained within the same file are more likely to be related and should be merged manually.

Comment: @isherwood I'm not expecting git to perform validation or determine that a change _will_ produce trampling or broken logic.  I want it to err on the side of caution when determining whether to automatically merge changes or produce a conflict, even if it produces false-positives.  A simple algorithm (the one I use in my custom merge driver) is to compare the file in both branches to the base file.  If the file in both branches differ from the base file, I produce a conflict.  Automatically merging files increases the _likelihood_ of undesirable results.

Comment: Fair enough, but that would be a nightmare for my company (and most others, I suspect). Same-file merges are a weekly, if not daily, occurrence, and what you're describing would render Git nearly pointless for us. Best of luck with your venture.

Comment: Git's mystery is only exceeded by its power.

Comment: git considers changes to a range of overlapping lines as a conflict, nothing else. For synchronization like what you want you have to install some people protocol ("Only Bob can futz around with the foo functionality, Alice is the sole owner of bar.c and baz.h, any interfase change has to be approved by Charlie"). And do regular build tests (e.g. each day at 10PM check out the latest tip of the official `master`, run a complete build and post the results for everybody to read (and possibly correct) first thing in the morning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem isn't unique to git.  Every version control system I'm aware of manages *textual* conflicts, not *semantic* conflicts.  In other words, git can detect if two people change the same line of code.  The only way to detect the kind of conflicts you are talking about would be to essentially compile the code as part of the conflict detection process.  Note that's not an entirely unfeasible thing to do, it's just that no one has gotten around to it yet.

For most teams, this situation does not come up very often.  If it happens to you a lot, you might want to look at the coupling of your design, or your communication with your teammate about how work is divided.

Comment: Thanks.  I've edited my question to clarify.  I don't want git to tell me the merge will result in broken code.  I want it to determine that the merge _may_ result in broken code by producing a conflict when the code in both branches differ from the common ancestor.  My custom merge driver does this.  I wanted to see how other people tackled the problem and whether there was a better way.

Comment: All your custom driver does is decrease the default line-by-line resolution for detecting conflicts to a file-by-file resolution.  If the deleted `foo()` was in a completely separate file from `bar()` and `baz()`, you'd be back in the same boat unless you manually resolve *every* merge.  This isn't a problem that source control is really equipped to solve, which is why we have things like continuous integration servers and unit testing.  *That's* the "better way" other people use to tackle the problem.

Comment: We're trying to move our code base in that direction, but our major in-house applications were designed many years ago so there's a lot of inertia (and plenty of copy-pasta) to overcome.  I'm also trying to come up with a solution that's as safe as possible as a single 'git screw-up' could turn some of our developers off of the whole thing.

Comment: Perhaps I erred in viewing git as a guard rail instead of as a safety net.  The fact that it goes as far as it does in helping you protect your code may have caused me to expect too much from it.  I'm going to keep my custom merge driver for now and probably add a step for running gitk or something similar to the merge workflow so the developer can scan all changes.  I would gladly add running unit tests, but that is simply not possible with the current code base.